# *ruby*how can i develop a Ruby program that prints the numbers of terms of Fibonacci series together with prime number as requested by the user

Tags: ruby, coding-style, helper

def
fib(n)
if (n <= 2)
return 1
else
return (fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))
end

end

puts " please enter the number of terms : -"
n=gets.chomp.to_i

puts "The first #{n} terms of Fibonacci series that are also prime numbers are:-"
for c in 1..n
puts fib(c)

end

Answer (score 0):

okay, I've separated out your code, and optimised it using a hash to save recalculating the series with each additional "n" ...

**Calculate all the Fibonacci numbers up to your chosen number**

```
@fibs={}
def calc_fibs(n)
  return @fibs[n] if @fibs[n]
  if (n <= 2)
    @fibs[n] = 1
  else
    @fibs[n] = (calc_fibs(n-1) + calc_fibs(n-2))
  end
  @fibs[n]
end
```

**the core program to get the number and show the prime terms**

```
require "prime"
def fib_go
  puts "please enter the number of terms : -"
  n=gets.chomp.to_i

  calc_fibs(n)

  puts "The first #{n} terms of Fibonacci series that are also prime numbers are:-"
  1.upto(n) do |c|
    puts @fibs[c] if Prime.prime?(@fibs[c])
  end
end
```

**Output:**

```
fib_go

please enter the number of terms : -
90
The first 90 terms of Fibonacci series that are also prime numbers are:-
2
3
5
13
89
233
1597
28657
514229
433494437
2971215073
99194853094755497
```

warning: numbers greater than 80 get really slow, with the "prime?" function

Answer (score -3):

Prompt user to enter the number of terms, then use the input to construct a loop
structure that generates Fibonacci series, but only those Fibonacci numbers which
are also prime numbers will be printed to the screen as the final output.